# Run previous task with when statement or rerun playbook based on condition

Tags: ansible

I have setup playbook and it runs fine without errors.
Now I have setup conditions for variable checking and it fails/stops playbook when certain variable is empty or not defined.

Sample code

```
 - name: Checking variables
   fail: 
    msg: " Input cant be empty, Please provide all information ."
   when: 
   -  var1  == ""  
   -  var2  == ""
   -  var3   == ""
   -  var4   == ""
```

> Whats working :  I take input from user, then check the provided input
> and skip/fail tasks bases on conditions.

My code:

```
   - name: var1
     prompt: "var1?"
     private: no
   - name: var2
     prompt: "var2?"
     unsafe: yes
     private: no 
   - name: var3
     prompt: "var3?"
     private: no
   - name: var4
     prompt: "var4 ?"
     private: no

  Tasks:
 - name: Checking variables
   fail: 
    msg: " Input cant be empty, Please provide all information ."
   when: 
   -  var1  == ""  
   -  var2  == ""
   -  var3   == ""
   -  var4   == ""
```

> Expected Result:  I take input from user, then check the provided
> input  move the playbook to input section again i.e asks user for
> required empty variables or run the playbook from beginning again and
> get user input again.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion here would be to use `action plugin` to prompt users for input instead of `prompts`. A good action plugin to prompt the user during playbook execution could be found at [this](https://gist.github.com/confiks/6d7b0ee3e137df01b758) place.(you may need to tweak it a bit for your requirement, as the current form only support `y`, `n`,`yes`,`no` as input.

Action plugin is a python program that could be controlled better with all sort of validations you could add, meaning you could keep asking the user for correct input until all validation of input are passed.

The requirement of action plugin is plugin should be placed inside a directory called `action_plugin` and this directory should be at the same level as of playbook.

Eg:

```
|-playbook-dir
   |_myplaybook.yml
   |-action_plugin
     |-prompt_user.py
```

Comment: can i find anything from within ansible plugins ?

Comment: @AsifShabbir sorry , I do not understand. would you explain

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use [*pause*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/pause_module.html#ansible-builtin-pause-pause-playbook-execution) instead of *vars_prompt*. *pause* is a task and can be put into the [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks), and [retried until a condition is met](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#retrying-a-task-until-a-condition-is-met).

> *"The default value for “retries” is 3 and “delay” is 5."*

For example

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - block:
        - pause:
            prompt: "var1?"
          register: result
          until: result.user_input|length > 0
        - set_fact:
            var1: "{{ result.user_input }}"
      rescue:
        - fail:
            msg: "Input can't be empty. Please provide all information."
      run_once: true
    - debug:
        var: var1
```

gives (no input '<ENTER>' only for the first time, then 'abc<ENTER>')

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb.yml

PLAY [all] ****

TASK [pause] ****
[pause]
var1?:
^MFAILED - RETRYING: pause (3 retries left).
[pause]
var1?:
ok: [test_01]

TASK [set_fact] ****
ok: [test_01]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [test_02] => 
  var1: abc
ok: [test_03] => 
  var1: abc
ok: [test_01] => 
  var1: abc
  ...

PLAY RECAP ****
test_01: ok=3 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
test_02: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
test_03: ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=0 skipped=0 rescued=0 ignored=0
  ...
```

The play will fail when no input is provided

```yaml
TASK [fail] ****
fatal: [test_01]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  msg: Input can't be empty. Please provide all information.
```